# Bokeh tutorial failed with iPython Notebook 3/ Jupyter

Tags: plot, jupyter-notebook, nameerror, bokeh, jupyter

I am still learning both iPython Notebook/Jupyter and how to plot with Bokeh. I am using the model steps from here: http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/bokeh/bokeh-notebooks/blob/master/tutorial/00%20-%20intro.ipynb#
But my code has failed on In[13]: in their example. From Bokeh it says:

```
In [13]:

from bokeh.models import Circle, HoverTool
from bokeh.palettes import Spectral6

renderer_source = ColumnDataSource(bubble_plot.get_1964_data())

def add_circles(plot):
    plot = add_text(plot)
    # Add the circle
    circle_glyph = Circle(
        x='fertility', y='life', size='population',
        fill_color='region_color', fill_alpha=0.8,
        line_color='#7c7e71', line_width=0.5, line_alpha=0.5)
    circle_renderer = plot.add_glyph(renderer_source, circle_glyph)

    # Add the hover (only against the circle and not other plot elements)
    tooltips = "@index"
    plot.add_tools(HoverTool(tooltips=tooltips, renderers=[circle_renderer]))
    return plot

show(add_circles(get_plot()))
```

My Code fails at the beginning second step. It is the following, as i am using my own data:

```
In [96]:

from bokeh.models import Circle, HoverTool

from bokeh.palettes import Spectral6

from bokeh.plotting import *

In [97]:

renderer_source = ColumnDataSource(bubble_plot.get_df())

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-97-8659183dfef3> in <module>()
----> 1 renderer_source = ColumnDataSource(bubble_plot.get_df())

NameError: name 'bubble_plot' is not defined
```

Why is `bubble_plot` undefined and how can I change that? It is exactly like in their example. No problems up to this point. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`bubble_plot` is defined in a separate python module. You can see at the top of the notebook, it does `import bubble_plot` to load that other module. You can see the contents here:

https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh-notebooks/blob/master/tutorial/bubble_plot.py

Comment: I know the results, I was trying to use it with my own data, which did not work. Thank you.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand your response. I didn't reiterate the results. You asked "Why is bubble_plot undefined and how can I change that?" and I answered that you need to obtain the `bubble_plot.py` module separately, and even gave you a link to do so.